# The entity or complex type 'OnStageTonight_MVC.Models2.GigViewModel' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query? Why not?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

It throws this error

The entity or complex type 'OnStageTonight_MVC.Models2.GigViewModel' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

when using this viewmodel

```
public class GigViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int gvmid { get; set; }
        public string bandname { get; set; }
        public string venuename { get; set; }
        public string address1 { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public DateTime whatdate { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan starttime { get; set; }        
    }
```

And with this controller method

```
string user = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var yourgigs = (from g in dbg.gigs
                            from v in dbg.Venues
                            from b in dbg.Bands
                            from ga in g.gigsaccasses
                            where (ga.Id == user &&
                            v.venueid == g.venueid &&
                            b.bandid == g.bandid)

                            select new GigViewModel
                            {
                                bandname = b.bandname,
                                venuename = v.venuename,
                                address1 = v.address1,
                                city = v.city,
                                whatdate = g.whatdate,
                                starttime = g.starttime
                            });
```

Apparently, it's something to do with not being able to project onto a mapped entity.  So I tried projecting on to an anonymous type,

```
string user = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var yourgigs = (from g in dbg.gigs
                            from v in dbg.Venues
                            from b in dbg.Bands
                            from ga in g.gigsaccasses
                            where (ga.Id == user &&
                            v.venueid == g.venueid &&
                            b.bandid == g.bandid)

                            select new
                            {
                                bandname = b.bandname,
                                venuename = v.venuename,
                                address1 = v.address1,
                                city = v.city,
                                whatdate = g.whatdate,
                                starttime = g.starttime
                            });
```

However, this threw the error about passing an anonymous type to a view that needs this specific model type

Where do I go from here?

Comment: One thing is not clear for me : why Do you have a class named "ViewModel" which is mapped to an entity ? ViewModels has usually nothing to do with entities...

Answer (score 0):

The first one would produce an `IQueryable<GigViewModel>`, is that what your view is expecting?

The second one won't work because you can't pass anonymous types to views (as the error message would indicate).

That said, I would make sure you have navigation properties set on your entity model correctly, then just pass a `List<gig>` or `IQueryable<gig>`.

```
var result=dbg.gigs
  .Include(g=>g.Venues)
  .Include(g=>g.Bands)
  .Where(g=>g.gigsaccasses.Any(ga=>ga==user))
  .ToList();  /* Optional if your DbContext is defined controller wide */
```

Then modify the view to display data from your gigs object.

If that is too difficult (which you will probably save yourself a lot of headaches later if you do), then do project to a List of anonymous objects, then since it is now LINQ over objects, project again to your final class although I'm not sure why it didn't work in the first place.

```
string user = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var yourgigs = (from g in dbg.gigs
                            from v in dbg.Venues
                            from b in dbg.Bands
                            from ga in g.gigsaccasses
                            where (ga.Id == user &&
                            v.venueid == g.venueid &&
                            b.bandid == g.bandid)

                            select new
                            {
                                bandname = b.bandname,
                                venuename = v.venuename,
                                address1 = v.address1,
                                city = v.city,
                                whatdate = g.whatdate,
                                starttime = g.starttime
                            })
                       .ToList()
                       .Select(g=>new GigViewModel
                            {
                                bandname=g.bandname,
                                venuename=g.venuename,
                                address1=g.address1,
                                city=g.city,
                                whatdate=g.whatdate,
                                starttime=g.starttime
                            });
```

Comment: This latter option throws the error

Cannot initialize type 'OnStageTonight_MVC.Models2.GigViewModel' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

at the line 
.Select(g=>new GigViewModel
                            {

Comment: Sorry, I can't explain that one.  It's not a collection initializer, it's an object initializer.  Do you have more than one GigViewModel in your project perhaps in a separate file? I've updated the answer to explicitly name the destination properties, but you shouldn't have to.  Try removing the [Key] attribute and gvmid property as well from GigViewModel.